# Is it possible to change the x scale of a rowchart to sqrt?

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, dc.js

I want to change the scale of the x axis of a row chart because some values are close to 0 but others are over 100000. I have tried this:

```
chart.x([d3.scaleSqrt().domain([0, 75000]).clamp(true)])
```

but it doesn't work.

However, this same method does work with a barchart. Any suggestions of how I can solve this?

EDIT: What I meant by 'it doesn't work' is that it shows the rowchart but the x axis is what comes by default, so there is no rescaling of the axis.

Comment: When you ask a question on Stack Overflow or anywhere, please provide more detail than "it doesn't work". Did you get an error in the console, did you get a blank chart, did it display wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you've got an extra set of brackets - that should be

```
chart.x(d3.scaleSqrt().domain([0, 75000]).clamp(true))
```

Since you don't say what didn't work, I will guess that you got a "squished" chart.

Here is what I got when I first tried this:

[image: squished row chart]

Unlike other dc.js charts, the row chart [will not set the *range* of the X scale](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1632) when the scale is passed in by the user.

For other charts, dc.js will initialize the range based on the "effective width" - the width of the chart minus the left and right margins.

We can do the same:

```
chart.x(d3.scaleSqrt()
          .domain([0, 75000])
          .range([0,chart.effectiveWidth()])
          .clamp(true)])
```

My example now looks like

[image: nice sqrt screenshot]